# Compute frame of UIView for a given device orientation

Tags: iphone, ios, layout, device-orientation

I need to handle all iOS screen ratios (3.5 inches, 4 inches). I am not using `autolayout` because I need `iOS` 5.x compatibility.

In my app I need to reorganize my buttons and icons when device orientation changes, switching from Portrait:

```
Logo
-
Button 1
Button 2
Button 3
```

to Landscape :

```
       Button 1
Logo   Button 2
       Button 3
```

Because of the different screen ratios, I need to adjust height of the Logo in Portrait based on the Y-position of Button 1, and to adjust width of the Logo in Landscape based on the X-position of Button 1.

To provide smooth animation, I would like to implement :

```
  - (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)
```

and start an animation that would run in the same timeline than the device's rotation animation. The problem is that I need the target frame of "Button 1" for my computation (the  frame after the device rotation) and I only have the frame of its initial state.

If I wait for the initial rotation to complete (which is what I implemented so far), you see that the app performs the rotation and THEN the positioning, which is... not satisfying for me.

So, in one single question, that would give :
"Is there a way to ask for the frame of a UIView given a specific device orientation ? Maybe the storyboard..."

It should be accessible somewhere, because the iOS animation has to compute this information to start its animation right ?

Comment: you need to use autoresizing mask...

Comment: Did you try auto resizing in XIB?

Comment: you should calculate the postion separately in portrait & landscape mode,  then use autoresizing mask to fit difference screen solution

Comment: Yes, of course I am using autosizing, but this is not enough since I have to move some elements. I cannot achieve what I want with autoresizing mask, my question is about how to compute the frame for a given orientation so that I can position my elements properly in synch with the device rotation animation

Answer (score 0):

One way to find the screen bounds is to do the following:

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```